# How to upload multiple files from the Django admin?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-file-upload

I want to upload multiple files in the Django admin, without having to place multiple FileField fields. The user can be able to manage the files in a simple way; delete or change each uploaded file but upload several at once.

the solution I see viable is to use several filefield but the problem is, i dont know how many files the user will upload

```
def case_upload_location(instance, filename):
    case_name = instance.name.lower().replace(" ", "-")
    file_name = filename.lower().replace(" ", "-")
    return "casos/{}/{}".format(case_name, file_name)


class Case(models.Model):
    name            = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    observations    = models.TextField(null = True, blank = True)
    number_folder    = models.CharField('Folder', max_length=250)


    file1 = models.FileField('file 1', upload_to=case_upload_location, null = True, blank = True)
    file2 = models.FileField('file 2', upload_to=case_upload_location, null = True, blank = True)
    file3 = models.FileField('file 3', upload_to=case_upload_location, null = True, blank = True)
    file4 = models.FileField('file 4', upload_to=case_upload_location, null = True, blank = True)
```

***Final Target***

Multiple files to upload(user need to delete or change one by one but upload all at once).

Comment: Why not have a separate model which just contains a file field and that can be linked to `Case` with a FK & you can add inlines via admin to add files

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Looks like you're in need one-many foreign key relationship from a "Case File" model to the "Case" model you've defined.

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

def case_upload_location(instance, filename):
    case_name = instance.name.lower().replace(" ", "-")
    file_name = filename.lower().replace(" ", "-")
    return "casos/{}/{}".format(case_name, file_name)

class Case(models.Model):
    # datos del caso
    name = models.CharField('Nombre', max_length=250)
    observations = models.TextField('Observaciones', null = True, blank = True)
    number_folder = models.CharField('Numero de Carpeta', max_length=250)

class CaseFile(models.Model):
    case = models.ForeignKey(Case, on_delete=models.CASCADE) # When a Case is deleted, upload models are also deleted
    file = models.FileField(upload_to=case_upload_location, null = True, blank = True)
```

You can then add a StackedInline admin form to add Case Files directly to a given Case.

**admin.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Case, CaseFile

class CaseFileAdmin(admin.StackedInline):
    model = CaseFile

@admin.register(Case)
class CaseAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [CaseFileAdmin]

@admin.register(CaseFile)
class CaseFileAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass
```